# Automatically Add Self Reference To Properties Of Object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, code-formatting

In Visual Studio 2019, when writing .net (C# or VB.net), is there a way to automatically prefix members/ properties of an object with their respective "self" reference?

Eg in c#, automatically prepending "`this.`" when referencing members of a class from within the class.

Eg in VB.net, automatically prepending "`me.`" when referencing members of a class from within the class.

Using an extension to do this is fine, if one exists.

Comment: so you have already written code, and now you want to write automatically the `this.` prefix in front of every property?

Comment: @MongZhu yes. That is correct.

Comment: When you have set the *Qualify field/property/method* in the language Code Style options, you can use `Edit-Advanced-Format Document` or `CTRL+K+D` to reformat the file currently opened: it will add all the missing `this/me` in the current file. See the option in `Code Style-Formatting-General-Perform additional code cleanup...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for **Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Code Style**
You will see a preference like;

> Qualify property access with 'this' |  Do not prefer 'this'

Change the option above and voila!

P.S: You still need to run code cleanup(ctrl+K+E) or set the severity to "Error", in which case VS itself will prompt to "fix" it as @stuartd mentions it in the comments

Comment: Well, you can set the severity to "Error", in which case VS itself will prompt to "fix" it.

Comment: If you set it to "Suggestion" the yellow bulb on the left side will appear and you will be able to apply this change at solution, project or document level.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works great. I cant seem to make it work with the code cleanup, but your answer is definitely correct.